# SQL Azure failover

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In case SQL Azure node fails, how does it work?

1. Do I lose any data? the latest committed
   data since the last
   backup/replication?
2. Is the data always replicated
   instantneously?

In the worst case scenario, what could happen to my committed data?

Cheers.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this is closed as off-topic. Programatically, you need to implement retries, as SQL Azure instances can (and do) go offline. It's a known pattern that must be followed when working with SQL Azure. And for Disaster Recovery (which isn't covered by replication), you need to configure data sync.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Azure always keeps data in three replicas (a primary and two standby). The first standby copy is done synchronously (ie in the same transaction) and the second asynchronously. Uncommited data may be lost but your commited data is safe.

When a hardware error the first standby is brought online. New connections are made to the new online copy. According to [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-connection-management-in-sql-azure.aspx) the failover is not transparent and may result in termination of your connection with a generic connection error (10053 or 40197).

Of course, if it *may* terminate, you have to assume it *will* terminate and your code will have to be prepared to retry failed transactions.